# Looping an IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to loop an "if" statement using javascript/jquery, example

```
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
if (name === '') {
    name = prompt("Try again");
alert(name);
}
```

using the code above, it would check once but then whatever the second answer is, it won't check, is there a way to make it check repetitively without writing the if statement a billion times...?

Comment: Just... use a loop instead of an `if` statement?

Comment: Use while loop and check condition while(name=="")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the "while" loop.

```
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
while (name === '') {
    name = prompt("Try again");
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: what about for an 'else if' statement? 'else while' dosen't work

Comment: Anything that follows after the while statement will happen only when the `while` condition is false. So that's your "else".